# Extending the ORM user model in kohana

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm new to Kohana and I'm trying to build an application using the ORM module. I created my own user module containing stuff like login, account creating etc. The problem however is that I can't seem to create a user model in my own user module extending the ORM one. If I understand kohana correctly I should name my user model: Model_User. The problem is, the ORM model I'm trying to extend is also called Model_User.

The reason I'm trying to create my own model is so I can add some extra methods and checks without modifying with the ORM user model.
So my question is:

How do I create a user model in my own module that extends the ORM user model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend pretty much everything in Kohana via the transparent class extensions: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/extension

In this case, the default ORM Model_User class is an empty (transparent) class that extends Model_Auth_User.

So if you want to add new methods to this model, just create a new Model_User model class that extends Model_Auth_User, in your module.

Due to Kohana's cascading file system, the model stored in your module will be used. http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files

[edit] Important to note, the order in which you enable the modules is important, see http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/modules

Comment: Extending Model_Auth_User still wouldn't work because it'd still use Model_User from the ORM (both classes are called Model_User). I'd have to delete the model in the ORM module to get my own model to work, which in my opinion seems wrong. I was hoping there'd be some kind of solution involving namespaces or a way to specify the module without having to alter the orm module.

Comment: Are you sure? ;) You don't need to delete anything. Please have another go at understanding my response. I mentioned the cascading file system, please read that page.

Comment: Also, related to the CFS, the order in which you enable your modules matter: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/modules